# access localhost on another computer with webmatrix

Tags: wordpress, iis, localhost, publish, webmatrix

so currently i am working on a wordpress site with webmatrix, and would like to view my progress in another computer in my network (at my workplace)

i want to either add the files to a shared drive for everyone on the network to view, or publish it locally with iis hosting

for the first method, i tried to change the url under settings from localhost:0000 to mycomputerIP:0000 but it did not work

for the second method i tried to enter the credentials of iss in the other computer into settings under publishing, so that it can be published locally, but it also did not work

i have looked for solutions online, but nothing seemed to be able to fix it, i am sorry for the vague description, but if anyone would like to help me i can provide more information

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to follow the instructions at the following link to make sure everything is setup correctly:

http://blogs.iis.net/vaidyg/archive/2010/07/29/serving-external-traffic-with-webmatrix-beta.aspx

---

**Edit**

If you are using Windows Vista, 7, 8 or 8.1 you could look at installing a local copy of IIS and creating a virtual server for your WebMatrix site. It's not as much work as it sounds and it will give you a full management console, host name bindings and all kinds of other advantages. The following link should get you started:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-install-iis-on-windows-vista/

Comment: i have just added port80, but it seemed to have been open all the time. the site is still not working unfortunately, might there be any other reasons?

Comment: @user3219859 I've updated my answer, I hope the link helps you.

Comment: i am currently trying out the steps given, however after step two which i sould be able to see my site, it shows error 404

is there a file called applicationhost.config that i can edit? because i have no idea what is going wrong right now

Comment: @user3219859 Strange, without more information it's difficult to diagnose your problem. I have made an additional suggestion (see edited answer).